# How can I install the PCNTL extension on Windows?

Tags: windows, phpunit, pcntl

I am running [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) in Windows and am trying to install PHPUnit via *composer.json*:

```
"phpunit/php-invoker": "*"
```

...with this dependency, but I am getting this error:

> phpunit/php-invoker 1.1.3 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.

How can I install this extension?

Answer (score 20):

You can't install the *ext-pcntl* extension on Windows. According to the PHP documentation:

> Currently, this module will not function on non-Unix platforms
> (Windows).

If you want to install [PHPUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit), all you need is the PHPUnit library:

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit 4.*
```

You don't need *php-invoker* to install PHPUnit. But if you also need the *php-invoker* library, you are out of luck. Try using [Vagrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagrant_%28software%29) or a plain VM with Linux distributions like [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), or [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint).

Answer (score 8):

If you're running on Windows 10 without [Laravel Homestead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features), you can enable the Linux subsystem and run your code through that.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10

Then install the requirements:

```bash
sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql
```

This also can run Laravel Envoy and Horizon too which don't work on Windows.

It's a nice lightweight solution.

Comment: can this run Nginx, MySQL, MongoDB, Supervisor, Crontabs and etc? cause if it can, it's like a mini server for development then

Comment: The `www.windowscentral.com` link is (effectively) broken: *"No articles found. The page you requested currently has no articles listed."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen the link seems back to normal, I can access it today

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using: `--ignore-platform-reqs ext-pcntl` when installing via commands.

Further information is at *[Laravel Horizon, ext-pcntl and Windows](https://oli-the.dev/development/laravel-horizon-ext-pcntl-and-windows/)*.

Answer (score 2):

Just this command helped me to update the composer

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

these `pcntl` and `posix` extension are for `UNIX` like systems