# How to enable pcntl in PHP (while using a framework like Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony

Consider:

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\login
php app/console server:start
```

This command needs the `pcntl` extension to run.

This is the error I get when I try to start the web server in my [Symfony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) 2 environment...

I found a fix, by using the command:

```
php app/console server:run
```

But why doesn't `server:start` work on my desktop?

My goal is to:

1. Starting the Web server
2. Running a Symfony application using PHP's built-in web server is as easy as executing the `server:start` command:

   ```
   php app/console server:start
   ```

Answer (score 19):

### On Windows

You can't install the `pcntl` extension on Windows. [According to the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php):

**Note:** This extension is not available on Windows platforms.

Try using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) or a plain virtual machine with a Linux distributions like [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/), [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) or [Mint](https://linuxmint.com/).

---

### On Unix

First, type in your command line in your home directory:

```
mkdir php
cd php
apt-get source php5
cd php5-(WHATEVER_RELEASE)/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make
```

Then do this:

```
cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php5/WHEVER_YOUR_SO_FILES_ARE/
echo "extension=pcntl.so" > /etc/php5/conf.d/pcntl.ini
```

Finished!

---

### On Mac

Taken from [an answer to *How can I enable process control extension (PCNTL) in PHP MAMP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230255/how-can-i-enable-process-control-extension-pcntl-in-php-mamp/8432855#8432855)!

There is a way of compiling PCNTL as an extension and linking it in to an existing PHP build, but it's a bit in-depth.

I'm doing the following on [Mac OS X v10.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard) (64bit), with [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) and PHP version 5.3.6. Remember to change PHP version numbers in the following lines if yours is different!

Please note that `make` is *required*, which isn't installed by default on Mac OS X. You need to install this via Mac developer tools, *http://developer.apple.com/unix/*.

First, download a tar of the PHP source code that matches the version you are using in MAMP (e.g., mine is 5.3.6), which you can do at *[Unsupported Historical Releases](http://www.php.net/releases/)*. Untar and [cd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to *php-[version]/ext/pcntl*, e.g.:

```
wget http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.3.6.tar.gz
tar xvf php-5.3.6.tar.gz
cd php-5.3.6/ext/pcntl
```

You then need to run `phpize` in the pcntl directory, which is a binary file that comes with MAMP:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpize
```

This creates a bunch of files that are needed for preparing an extension for compiling.

We now need to add some flags to tell it to compile the library with dual 32-bit and 64-bit architecture, as the MAMP PHP has been built this way. If you don't do this, the compiled shared objects won't work.

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
CCFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
LDFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CCFLAGS MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

We can then run `./configure` and `make` to build our shared object:

```
./configure
make
```

This puts a file called `pcntl.so` in the *modules* directory. Copy this file to your MAMP's PHP extensions directory:

```
cp modules/pcntl.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

Finally, edit the PHP INI file to include the extension:

```
echo "extension=pcntl.so" >> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
```

PCNTL should now be enabled. To check to see whether it has been added, just run:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php --ri pcntl

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled
```

If you see that, it's worked!

---

### Helpful resources

For Windows:

- *[How can I install PCNTL extension in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045085/how-to-install-pcntl-extension-in-windows)*
- *[Use proc_open() instead of pcntl_fork() in simpletest](https://www.drupal.org/node/771448)*

For Unix operating systems:

- http://www.crimulus.com/2010/07/30/howto-enable-pcntl-in-ubuntu-php-installations/

For Mac:

- *[How can I enable process control extension (PCNTL) in PHP MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230255/how-to-enable-process-control-extension-pcntl-in-php-mamp)*
- *[Installing PCNTL module for PHP without recompiling](https://serverfault.com/questions/158113/installing-pcntl-module-for-php-without-recompiling)*

Other information:

- *[[DX] Show a message if server:start is missing pcntl #12153](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12153)*

Comment: Solid answer - but I think it would be helpful if you placed your sources closer to each excerpt and explicitly block quoted those excerpts. As written, I think someone could make a case that not using block quote formatting is dishonest.

Comment: @HPierce: Re *"dishonest"* Yes, it is plagiarism. It needs to be quoted (at a minimum. That may not even be enough). Is wholesale copying of other answers OK, even if attributed and quoted?

Comment: There must be a meta question somewhere. Starting points are *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)* and *[How much can be quoted before it is considered plagiarism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343641/how-much-can-be-quoted-before-it-is-considered-plagiarism)*.

Comment: A precedent: *[Why was my answer deleted for plagiarism, despite mentioning the source?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421874/)*

Answer (score 5):

The [php-extension-library at GitHub](https://github.com/jrquick17/php-extension-library) has several pcntl.so files which you can easily download for your version of PHP and add to your extensions and *.ini* files.

For example, for PHP version 7.3.9:

1. Download `pcntl.so` [from the repository here](https://github.com/jrquick17/php-extension-library/blob/master/php7.3.9/pcntl.so) or [directly here](https://github.com/jrquick17/php-extension-library/raw/master/php7.3.9/pcntl.so).
2. Move `pcntl.so` file to extensions (Example: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.9/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-xxxxxxxx`)
3. Add `extension=pcntl.so` to your `.ini`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `pcntl` extension in your system. This is part of the `php-cli` package, so you just need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-cli
```

Check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks.., i am using Windows instead of iOs. So the command differs for my environment :)

I hope i will find the right commando in the doc u linked!

Answer (score 4):

## For Docker

You can use [docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) like this:

```yaml
# Dockerfile
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions pcntl
```

Then activate the extension in your *php.ini* file:

```
extension=pcntl.so
```

Comment: Why `uga+x`? Isn't `a+x` sufficient ([exactly the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Symbolic_modes))? The same as `ugo+x`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The documentation (https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer#usage) used to say to run `chmod uga+x` now it's only `chmod +x`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the following script to install the *pcntl* extension for [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) on our Ubuntu systems, which works at least on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), and I anticipate will also work on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver), as well as other distributions with a similar PHP/Apache packaging/installation layout:

```
#! /bin/bash

php_ver=$(php -r 'print(join(".",array_slice(explode(".",phpversion()), 0, 2)));')
php_api_ver=$(php-config --phpapi)
pkg="php$php_ver"
mods_dir=/usr/lib/php/$php_api_ver/
php_conf_dir=/etc/php/$php_ver/apache2/conf.d
set -e
work_dir=/tmp/php-pcntl
rm -rf $work_dir
mkdir -p $work_dir
cd $work_dir
apt-get source $pkg
cd $pkg-$php_ver.*/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make -j 8
sudo cp modules/pcntl.so $mods_dir
echo "extension=pcntl.so" | sudo tee $php_conf_dir/10-pcntl.ini > /dev/null
echo "pcntl extension installed, now restart Apache and make sure it really works"
```

You will possibly need to take care a few prerequisites in addition to the regular Apache/PHP install: `apt-get install php-dev php-cli`, then edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure the appropriate `deb-src` line is not commented, and run `apt-get update`. Then you can just run the script and it should take care of the install. If everything is good, `rm -rf /tmp/php-pcntl` - I intentionally left that step out of the script in case something goes wrong and I need to debug the contents of that directory.

Note that you will need to make sure that your `php.ini` does not disable your functions of interest with `disable_functions=`. E.g., on Ubuntu 16.04 `pcntl_signal()` along with a few others are disabled with an explicit `php.ini` directive.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no options to enable `pcntl` in Windows machine.
As per [php official documentation about pcntl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php)

[See what php official documentation about pcntl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXgcA.png)