# Symfony3 console running console command from controller

Tags: php, symfony, command

I am trying to run console command from my controller using Process Component, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
     $process = new Process('php bin/console mycommand:run');
     $process->setInput($myArg);
     $process->start();
```

I also tried:

```
    $process = new Process('php bin/console mycommand:run ' . $myArg)
    $process->start();
```

I run my command using:

```
php bin/console mycommand:run my_argument
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does „it does not work“ mean? Is there any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is path. Anyway you should consider not using `Process` to call Symfony Commands. Console components is allowing to call commands e.g. in controller.

Example from docs:

```
// src/Controller/SpoolController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class SpoolController extends Controller
{
    public function sendSpoolAction($messages = 10, KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
           'command' => 'swiftmailer:spool:send',
           // (optional) define the value of command arguments
           'fooArgument' => 'barValue',
           // (optional) pass options to the command
           '--message-limit' => $messages,
        ));

        // You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
        $content = $output->fetch();

        // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Using this way you're sure that code will always work. When PHP is in safe mode (`exec` etc. are turned off) `Process` component is useless. Additionally you don't need to care about paths and other things otherwise the situation you're call command 'manually'.

You can read more about calling commands from controller [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html).

Comment: I tried this method before and it worked out, but I also wanted to be able to stop the command after it run. With Process I could just retrive the pid somewhere and later kill the process. What are my options with this solution if I would be able to kill the command, I heard it's possible with pcntl_signals, but as you can see in my previous thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941237/symfony3-command-pcntl-doesnt-works 

It didn't worked for me.

Comment: @SakuragiRokurota your best bet is using message queue. This way your controller only sends message to the queue, and command processing will be separated from HTTP request.