# how to solve laravel/horizon v4.3.3 requires ext-pcntl problem

Tags: php, laravel, pcntl, horizon

I'm using Windows operating system. I've also tried with these solutions available here:
link 1) [PHP pcntl module installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053934/php-pcntl-module-installation/41597346#41597346)
link 2) [How to install PCNTL extension in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045085/how-to-install-pcntl-extension-in-windows/30085212#30085212)

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/horizon v4.3.3 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
    - laravel/horizon v4.3.2 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
    - laravel/horizon v4.3.1 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
    - laravel/horizon v4.3.0 requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
    - laravel/horizon 4.x-dev requires ext-pcntl * -> the requested PHP extension pcntl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/horizon ^4.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/horizon[4.x-dev, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: Use docker for your dev environment? ;)

Answer (score 0):

"platform": {
"ext-posix": "8.2",
"ext-pcntl": "8.2"
},

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code segment in your composer.json file.

```
"config": {
   "platform": {
      "ext-pcntl": "8.0",
      "ext-posix": "8.0"
   }
 }
```

I was facing the exact same problem. This worked like a charm for me.